# Passing the path of a file as an argument in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script like this where I pass in a file path into it

```
groups=$1
file=$2

if $groups
then
    sh with_groups.sh $file
else
    sh without_groups.sh $file
fi
```

What I currently do: Open the folder where my file is, do `pwd`, copy the link, add `some_csv.csv` to it and run the above script. I want to find a more efficient way to do it.

The equivalent of what I would would be something like

```
sh ./../run_script.sh true pwd/some_csv.csv
```

where pwd is the current path I am in (true refers to the first argument. You can disregard that for the purpose of this question)

Comment: `what I would would be something like` then do exactly that. (?) What are you asking exactly about? To get current path in shell, use `$(pwd)`. Check your script with shellcheck.

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't know `$(pwd)` does that. Thanks a lot.